# R: tmap Legend Formatting

Tags: r, format, legend, tmap

I am trying to create a function to map different variables for a specific state's school districts. However I a running into some problems formatting the legend. At the moment I have it laid out the best way to fit the maps(horizontally), but some of the text is being cut off (Below Average Poverty Rate), and I'd like to add % to the number labels in the legend. My code and an image of the legend is below. Any help you can provide would be very much appreciated. Thank You.

```
MakeLEAMap <-function(StateNum,NCHE_VAR,VAR1_NAME,In,Folder){
  as.character(substitute(StateNum))
  as.character(substitute(NCHE_VAR))
  as.character(substitute(NCHE_In))
  as.character(substitute(VAR1_NAME))
  as.character(substitute(Folder))

  map <- 
    tm_shape(LEA_1415_New[LEA_1415_New@data$STATEFP == StateNum, ]) +
    tm_polygons(NCHE_VAR,border.col="#000000", lwd= .5, textNA="Below Average \nPoverty Rate" ,  palette = 'Blues', style="quantile", 
                title=paste(In," State LEA Map: ",VAR1_NAME),
                legend.is.portrait = FALSE) +
    tm_text("LCITY", size=NCHE_VAR,scale=.8, root=2,print.tiny = FALSE, size.lowerbound = .85, bg.alpha = .75, 
            remove.overlap = TRUE,legend.size.show = FALSE, col="black") +
    tm_layout( legend.title.size = 3,
              frame = FALSE, inner.margins = c(0,.0,.05,.0), asp = 1.5,
              legend.text.size = 1, 
              legend.outside=TRUE, legend.outside.position = 'bottom',
              legend.frame = TRUE,
              legend.outside.size = .3, legend.position = c(-0.1, 0.3))

  save_tmap(map, filename=paste("State_Maps_TEST/",Folder,"/",In,".pdf", sep = ''),width=8, height=8 ) 
}
MakeLEAMap("48","Abv_Diff_Home_Pov","% Children in Poverty  minus \n% Children HCY (Ages5-17)", 
           "TX","ALL")
```

[Here is what the legend looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQn6M.png)

Comment: I think this is relevant: [Formatting numbers in legends](https://github.com/mtennekes/tmap/issues/67)

Answer (score 7):

To make the legend show percentages use this function inside your `tm_polygons` call:

> legend.format=list(fun=function(x) paste0(formatC(x, digits=0, format="f"), " %"))

You can play with the digits (decimal points) and you can drop the space before % sign if you desire.

To make the legend more legible increase the space around your map by making a bigger bbox (possibly using `extent` function from `raster` package to read bbox of your spatial object and then enlarging it) and move the legend by adjusting its position.

This is what I came up with in a different context, but one which also called for a percentage sign in `tmap` legend.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Jindra Lacko's answer was extremely helpful. Just to add, if you want to convert scale components from decimals to percents, you can use the `scales` package. For example, if one row of your data showed a range of .1 to .2, the format could be changed with:

```
legend.format = list(fun=function(x) paste0(scales::percent(x))
```

Updated to add space between equals sign thanks to Jakub Malecki's good note.

Comment: The convention in R is to add surrounding spaces arround "=", like `legend.format = list(...)`